# test if jms listener is working

Tags: testing, jms, listener

i want to test if the JMS listener is working !
 to do that i want to test if the Queue size do not change for more than 5 seconds that means that the listener is not working
what should i add to my code please

```
        try {
        if ((msgIdMap.contains(tm.getJMSMessageID())) || !(message instanceof TextMessage)) {

            System.out.println("\tListener not working !");
        } else {

                process((TextMessage) message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the listener is designed, coded and configured correctly it should be working unless there's a problem with the provider.  If there is a problem with the provider, the client portion of the provider should detect it and call your ExceptionListener, if it is defined.

So, I would provide an ExceptionListener, by having your class implement the ExceptionListener:

```
public class MyJMSClass implements javax.jms.ExceptionListener {
```

then set the listener on the connection to this class:

```
connection.setExceptionListener(this);
```

then provide the recovery code:

```
public void onException(JMSException jmse) {
    log.error("JMS exception has occured.. ", jmse);

    // handle exception appropriately, perhaps by attempting to reconnect
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but how to reconnect ? and please tell me where to add your code ? il the producer class or in the consmer class ?